# Forcing Speedbar's Sorting Order of Org File Headers to Mirror File's

Tags: org-mode, speedbar

I use both org-sidebar (https://github.com/alphapapa/org-sidebar/) and Speedbar to navigate Org files.  Both have minor issues.  However, I find Speedbar works best, but it has a terrible habit of sorting headers in an order different to that of the file.  In particular, headings with no sub-headings (such as when drafting an outline) are always displayed after headings with sub-headings.  Does anybody know how to force the headeings' sort order in Speedbar to match that of the file's?

Comment: Type `C-h v` and have a look at the doc-string for `speedbar-tag-hierarchy-method` ("*List of hooks which speedbar will use to organize tags into groups.*"), which has options such as:  `speedbar-prefix-group-tag-hierarchy`; `speedbar-trim-words-tag-hierarchy`; `speedbar-simple-group-tag-hierarchy`; `speedbar-sort-tag-hierarchy`.  You can even write your own sorting functions ....  Or, you can have no sorting order -- which may be what you want (although I am unsure from the question because there is no before and after example).

Comment: ... continued from comment above:  To see what those functions do, type `C-h f` and read the doc-strings ... perhaps they will mention something you may find useful ....  And, if you are super interested, you can type `M-x find-function` and peek at the source code ....

Comment: @lawlist, you are correct in your assumption.  I don't want Speedbar to sort the headings.  I assume this will force their display in the same order as they appear in the file.  How do I accomplish this?  Do I 

    (setq speedbar-tag-hierarchy-method nil)

Comment: Because you have not provided a before/after example, I have no way to test your desired output and I don't even know what version of org-mode you are using.  With that being said, you can see what the default value is for `speedbar-tag-hierarchy-method` and modify it with `(setq speedbar-tag-hierarchy-method '(NAME-OF-FUNCTION-ONE NAME-OF-FUNCTION-TWO))`.  Eliminate the offending sorting function, save, restart Emacs and give it a whirl.

Comment: Let me try your suggestion.  I will post examples following my test

Comment: @lawlist, I want to thank you much.  Your suggestion worked perfectly.  I set the variable to nil. This forces Speedbar to display headers in the same order as they appear in the Org file.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `speedbar-tag-hierarchy-method` has a doc-string that states in relevant part:  "*List of hooks which speedbar will use to organize tags into groups.*"  The list can contain values such as:  `speedbar-prefix-group-tag-hierarchy`; `speedbar-trim-words-tag-hierarchy`; `speedbar-simple-group-tag-hierarchy`; `speedbar-sort-tag-hierarchy`.

The original poster has stated a preference that the tags *not* be sorted; i.e., that the order in which they appear be the same as the order in the file from which they were gathered.  In a comment underneath the question, the O.P. has indicated that he is happy with setting the above-mentioned variable to `nil`.  It may be preferable, however, to nevertheless keep a non-offending value such as trimming the words; e.g.

```lisp
(setq speedbar-tag-hierarchy-method '(speedbar-trim-words-tag-hierarchy))
```